# How to run dj file-type in Ruby script from terminal

Tags: ruby

The following code  is in file named test.dj. The file belongs to a code base internally developed in Ruby with no accurate documentation:

```
entity :bob do
  action :say_hi do
    puts "Hello!"
  end
end
```

How can I run this code from the command prompt?  When I try to run it like this:

```
$ruby test.dj
```

I get the error message:

```
test.dj:1:in `<main>': undefined method `entity' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

The only gem I see is Hdk but I can't find its documentation on the web either.

Comment: You can't compile ruby. Regardless, entity is from some library.

Comment: Why is this question tagged [distributed]?

Comment: @Jordan if you notice, the file extension is .dj which stands for distributed jobs

Comment: please don't -ve rep without putting a plausible explanation. This is unethical

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages, and "[mcve]". You haven't told us enough to help you, and it sounds like you are shooting in the dark hoping we'll write a tutorial for you. Instead, give us more detail, such as where you found that code. Then, if it's from a gem or an app, research that and see what you learn. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421 will help.

Comment: The [tag:distributed] tag which is for "Multiple computers working together, using a network to communicate". It's not for "distributed jobs" which would be a gem or application. See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/distributed/info for more information.

Comment: I see -ve votes without plausible explanation. If you can't help a person improve his question, at least stay away from -ve voting. This is very immoral.

Comment: The question seems perfectly legal and meets all the requirements Jorg W Mittag, @the Tin Man, zx485 and Julian F. Weinert, open up your minds

Comment: Stack Overflow has the goal of being an online reference site for programming problems. As such the quality of the questions asked, and the answers given, are important. You, and your peers, everyone using the site, is tasked with maintaining that quality. [meta] is where we discuss the needs and goals of the site and make decisions on what are appropriate types of questions. Then we vote on questions and answers to keep the site on path. Your peers determined your question doesn't meet those goals. We don't need to open our minds, perhaps you need to align with the goals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script is indeed Ruby code, but it is not stand-alone Ruby code.  It is is a program in a Ruby internal DSL.  That DSL is defining the methods "entity" and "action", which are not a part of Ruby.

Scripts written in a DSL are intended to be executed by that DSL.  There is likely to be another command that should be used to invoke this script.  I don't know what that command will be.  Assuming the command were called "distributed_jobs", then you might execute this script thusly:

```
distributed_jobs test.dj
```

But only the documentation for the DSL you are using can answer how to execute this script.

Comment: Superb. You are right the command to run this script is dj. The reason for asking this question was to find about DSL and see if only Ruby can be used to run this script.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, it is frequently useful to look for files named `Rakefile`, `Gemfile`, or `config.ru`.

### Rakefile

“Rake” is a **R**uby M**ake** tool that you can run as a CLI. It will look for a `Rakefile` authored in Ruby to define functionality. You can also run `$ rake -T` to get a list of available commands, of which `test` will hopefully be one.

### Gemfile

Most Ruby projects use Bundler to manage dependencies. If the previous developer declared a dependency, you could potentially find it in the Gemfile. If this is present, running `$ bundle install` in the directory should install the dependencies (note: you may need to run `gem install bundler` first).

### config.ru

This is known as a “rackup” configuration, which allows a Ruby app to run as a Rack webserver app. I doubt you'll find this in your project, but if you do, it could give you clues on the dependencies or libraries being utilized.